# mysql between current year and current year + 6 months

Tags: mysql

I need to make query where is where condition date between current year and current year + 6 months

```
SELECT VOZ.prez_vozac,VOZ.ime_vozac,LOD.naz_lok,LDO.naz_lok,V.datum
    FROM voznja AS V
    INNER JOIN vozac AS VOZ ON V.sif_vozac = VOZ.sif_vozac
    INNER JOIN lokacija AS LOD ON V.sif_lok_od = LOD.sif_lok
    INNER JOIN lokacija AS LDO ON V.sif_lok_do = LDO.sif_lok
    INNER JOIN vozilo AS VOZI ON V.regbr = VOZI.regbr
    INNER JOIN teret AS T ON V.sif_teret = T.sif_teret
    WHERE T.tezina <= 5 AND V.datum BETWEEN ***CURENT YEAR*** AND ***CURRENT YEAR + 6 MONTHS ***
```

Comment: What datatype is `v.datum`?

Comment: Current year did you mean current date ?

Comment: no current year from 2015.1.1 - 2015.6.1  or next year 2016.1.1 - 2016.6.1      ... V.datum is date type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean current date and six months from now...

```
   SELECT VOZ.prez_vozac,VOZ.ime_vozac,LOD.naz_lok,LDO.naz_lok,V.datum
    FROM voznja AS V
    INNER JOIN vozac AS VOZ ON V.sif_vozac = VOZ.sif_vozac
    INNER JOIN lokacija AS LOD ON V.sif_lok_od = LOD.sif_lok
    INNER JOIN lokacija AS LDO ON V.sif_lok_do = LDO.sif_lok
    INNER JOIN vozilo AS VOZI ON V.regbr = VOZI.regbr
    INNER JOIN teret AS T ON V.sif_teret = T.sif_teret
    WHERE T.tezina <= 5 AND V.datum BETWEEN CURDATE() 
AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

Comment: i know that but i need from first day in current year

Comment: CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-01-01')